# Non-static data member in concept definition

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++-concepts

If one (accidentally) mentions non-static data member of a class in the definition of a concept, what is expected value of the concept?

For example,

```
struct B {
    bool b;
};

template <typename T>
concept C1 = std::bool_constant<T::b>{}();
// #1 true in Clang and GCC, false in MSVC
static_assert( !C1<B> );

template <typename T>
concept C2 = T::b;
// #2 ok in Clang, errors in GCC and MSVC
static_assert( !C2<B> );
```

Here `!C1<B>` is evaluated to `true` in Clang and GCC, and to `false` in MSVC.

And `!C2<B>` is evaluated to `true` in Clang. But in GCC and MSVC it is a hard error.
GCC:

```
error: '*(B*)(void)0' is not a constant expression
```

MSVC:

```
error C7607: atomic constraint should be a constant expression of type 'bool', not 'unknown'
```

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/eGds9nhTx

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: Thanks to Jan answer below, I reported [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=110497) and [MSVC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Wrong-evaluation-of-std::bool_constant-i/10404998) issues.

Answer (score 0):

GCC is correct here.

Non-static data members are allowed be to be used without an object in unevaluated operands [[expr.prim.id.general]p(3.3)](https://wg21.link/expr.prim.id.general#3.3):

> An *id-expression* that denotes a non-static data member or implicit object member function of a class can only be used:
>
> - [...]
> - if that *id-expression* denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand.
>   [*Example 3:*
>
>   ```cpp
>   struct S {
>     int m;
>   };
>   int i = sizeof(S::m);           // OK
>   int j = sizeof(S::m + 42);      // OK
>   ```
>
>   — *end example*]

And the type of `T::b` with `T = B` in the concept is `bool`, the type of the non-static data member.

Obviously `B::b` isn't a `bool` constant expression, so `std::bool_constant<T::b>` is an invalid type ([[temp.arg.nontype]p2](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#2) if you really need a reference), and ([[expr.prim.req.general]p5](https://wg21.link/expr.prim.req.general#5)):

> The substitution of template arguments into a *requires-expression* may result in the formation of invalid types or expressions in its *requirements* or the violation of the semantic constraints of those *requirements*. In such cases, the *requires-expression* evaluates to `false`; it does not cause the program to be ill-formed.

So `C1<B>` is simply `false`.

However, with `C2<B>` is an atomic constraint, so needs to be (with `E = T::b`) [[temp.constr.atomic]p3](https://wg21.link/temp.constr.atomic#3.sentence-3):

> `E` shall be a constant expression of type `bool`.

... where it is not a constant expression, so this is a hard error.

---

Clang's error is thinking `T::b` is invalid in naming a non-static data member in an unevalated context, making `C2<B>` have an invalid expression and be `false`.

MSVC's error seems to be `T::b` is replaced with the constant expression `true` for some reason?

Comment: How is GCC correct if it straight up fails to compile with a nonsense error? Substitution fails into the atomic constraints, so the whole constraint-expression should be false in both cases. Clang is correct, not the failing compilers.

Comment: Why are you bringing up a paragraph about a *requires-expression*? There is no `requires` anywhere. We only have a `concept` with an atomic constraint.

Comment: @JanSchultke GCC's error message is a bit broken, but that's not really a problem. The expression `T::b` in the definition of `C2` is an unevaluated operand per https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.concept#6 and so this answer seems correct to me in determining that substitution should succeed.

Comment: @user17732522 even if use of `T::b` is legal in this context, it's being passed as a template argument to `std::bool_constant`, so what is the value of this `std::bool_constant` even supposed to be? `S::b` has no value, so are we referring to `std::bool_constant<false>` or `std::bool_constant<true>`? The answer is that this is nonsense, substitution should fail, and any compiler that accepts this has a problem.

Comment: @JanSchultke It is invalid in the definition of C1 because the template argument to `std::bool_constant` is _not_ an unevaluated context. But it is valid in C2. It then presumably fails being a constant expression as this answer also notes.

Comment: @JanSchultke I think it simply fails being a constant expression due to https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.9 for the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion applied per https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.atomic#3.sentence-3 since the expression `T::b` would be an lvalue expression that can be converted. (Also, in the comment above I meant "operand", not "context".)

Comment: I see, the answer seems correct then, but referring to *requires-expressions* as a rationale for why `C1<B>` is `false` seems like nonsense to me; there is no `requires` expression used here. The relevant paragraph is https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.constr#temp.constr.atomic-3

Comment: @user17732522 and Artyer, there is https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.atomic#3.sentence-4 which says "evaluated". The only unevaluated thing here is the whole thing to the right of `=` (before splitting it to atomic constraints), because it doesn't use the normal evaluation logic. Individual atomic constraints themselves have to be evaluated, because we use their values. This would make Clang correct.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sounds reasonable. Then the conclusion would indeed be that Clang is correct and it avoids some weirdness that would come with evaluating an unevaluated operand to determine satisfaction.